# Ubuntu server 22.04 fails to install in existsing LVM

Tags: server, 22.04, lvm

Trying to install Ubuntu server 22.04 it fails to install on existing LVM.  I have created a new lv for 22.04 and told to format and mount on /.  Swap on existing swap and told boot device.  Fails every time even when updating the installer on line.  Have read that 20.04 had the same problem, is the fix not propagated? Link to 20.04 issue is https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1878890

My curtain install.log says:

```
An error occured handling 'partition-sdb1': RuntimeError - 
Verifying /dev/sdb1 partition flag, expecting swap, found None
```

sudo fdisk -l under running 20.04 says:

```
Device   Boot Start     End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1 *    2048 4098047 4096000   2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Update 2022-07-27 - Tried installing without specifying swap and then it works and even enables swap on the right partition.

Comment: I'll try to get more info.  I was thinking of this 20.04 issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1878890 - J

Comment: Thanks, updated the issue